# Optional pagination

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to implement simple db query with optional pagination. My try:

```
def getEntities(limit: Option[Int], offset: Option[Int]) = {

  // MyTable is a slick definition of the db table 

  val withLimit = limit.fold(MyTable)(l => MyTable.take(l))    // Error here. 
                                                               // Mytable and MyTable.take(l) 
                                                               // has various types
  val withOffset = offset.fold(withLimit)(o => withLimit.drop(o))
  val query = withOffset.result

  db.run(query)
}
```

The problem is an error:

> type mismatch:
>     found: slick.lifted.Query
>     required: slick.lifted.TableQuery

How to make this code runnable? And maybe a little bit prettier?

---

My current fix to get `Query` from `TableQuery` is to add `.filter(_ => true)`, but IMHO this is not nice:

```
val withLimit = limit.fold(MyTable.filter(_ => true))(l => MyTable.take(l))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
val MyTable = TableQuery[SomeTable]
```

with

```
val MyTable: Query[SomeTable, SomeTable#TableElementType, Seq] = TableQuery[SomeTable]
```

i.e. to specify the type (statically upcast `TableQuery` to `Query`).

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Replaced fake filter: `limit.fold(MyTable: Query[..])(l => MyTable.take(l))`

Comment: Your post(thinking about types) gives to me a new idea. Works fine with `.map` without type specifying: `limit.map(l => MyTable.take(l)).getOrElse(MyTable)`